# Visual Web Developer 2010 Express hangs when adding web reference

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services, visual-web-developer

When attempting to add a web reference to my MVC 4 project I do the following:

-Right click on project name and select "Add Service Reference..."

-Click on "Advanced..." button

-Click on "Add Web Reference..." button

-Enter the Web Services API WSDL address in the URL field

At this point it will search and then find the web service and ask me to authenticate the request, after agreeing to continue I am prompted with a login dialog, after entering the correct username and password it will often lock up.  Sometimes it will re-display the login dialog and/or pop up some security confirmation boxes that read "Do you want to view only the webpage content that was delivered securely?" (Haven't been able to select Yes or No yet due to application hang around this time).

At this point I have to close the IDE and start the process over.  I've tried 5+ times and have updated my system and rebooted.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it just took a very very long time.  When clicking on pop ups it would stop responding, I found if I waited long enough it would eventually let me make a selection, then the next box would hang.  Whole process took well over 20min but eventually went through.

Not sure if this question should be deleted since technically there was no error, I'll leave it up to the mods.

Thanks.